# Inefficient double lengthening PRG

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, polynomial-time, pseudo-random-generators

I'm trying to prove that an inefficient double-lengthening PRG exists, i.e. construct a PRG $G: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{2n}$

My current approach is to bound the number of poly-time non-uniform algorithms as the number of boolean circuits, which is $2^{n^2}$, then we can say there $2^{n^2}$ functions, we will call them $F_i, 1 \leq i \leq 2^{n^2}$.
Then we will have $2^{2n}$ variables, each $t_{i}, 1 \leq i \leq 2^{2n}$,
and we will want to bound the $min ( {max_{1 \leq j \leq 2^{n^2}}} (\sum_{1\leq x \leq2^{2n}} t_x F_j(x))  - \sum_{1\leq x \leq2^{2n}} F_j(x)))$

with the constraints that:
$\sum_{1 \leq x \leq 2^{2n}} t_x = 2^n$
and $\forall 1 \leq x \leq 2^{2n}, 0 \leq t_x$

My aim is to show that this minimum is surely negligible, but I don't have a lot of background on constraint equations and I'm not sure if perhaps it's the right approach

thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/109801/351.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.